# Translating RPM specfile to build debian

Tags: ubuntu, package, bazaar

I'm familiar with using alien, but am trying to create a method to build my application with bzr builddeb rather than translating an rpm (via alien).

Specifically, how do I mimick the %dir and %attr behavior from an rpm spec in the debian package build environment?

Here's a snippet of my rpm spec:

```
%files
%defattr(-,root,root)
%dir /some/directory/
%dir /some/directory/name
%dir /some/directory/name/1
%dir /some/directory/name/2
%attr(0755,root,root)/some/directory/name/X
%attr(0644,root,root)/some/directory/name/file1
%attr(0755,root,root)/some/directory/name/file2
%attr(0644,root,root)/some/directory/name/1/file3
%attr(0644,root,root)/some/directory/name/1/file4
```

I am following the Ubuntu Packaging Guide, http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/packaging-new-software.html

I've read tons of guides that mention debian/install, debian/%packagename.install, and debian/rules changes and none have worked for me. I have a feeling these aren't doing what I want, which is to include files in the package that are created when the .deb is installed.

Comment: You might want to take a look at spec2deb --
 I don't know if they address your issue, but if they do then their Python source might help you.  Project is at: https://bitbucket.org/gdraheim/spec2deb